# In LINQ how to use column value passed to IQueryable function with func<T,T2>

Tags: c#, linq, predicate, func

Let's say I have this function to **add a simple filter** to my query:

```
    public static IQueryable<MyType> FilterSpecificParam(this IQueryable<MyType> query, string param)
    {

        var req = query.Where(c =>
            (!(param == null || param.Trim() == "") && c.SpecificColumn.StartsWith(param))
                   || ((param == null || param.Trim() == "")));

        return req;
    }
```

I would use it like this:

```
SomeQueryOnMyTable.FilterSpecificParam(MyFilter)
```

Now, I don't want to repeat such a function for every filter I want to set! So, I figured out that I could write my query like this :

```
SomeQueryOnMyTable.FilterGenericParam(MyFilter, c => c.TheColumnIWantToTest))
```

having this prototype for my function:

```
        public static IQueryable<MyType> Filter(this IQueryable<MyType> query, string param, Func<MyType, string> predicate)
```

**The problem:**
I don't manage to get a hand on the value of the column:

```
        public static IQueryable<MyType> Filter(this IQueryable<MyType> query, string param, Func<MyType, string> predicate)
    {

        var req = query.Where(c =>
            (!(param == null || param.Trim() == "") && predicate.Invoke(What???).StartsWith(param))
                   || ((param == null || param.Trim() == "")));

        return req;
    }
```

Notice the **predicate.Invoke** in the code above: it asks for an argument of type *MyType*.

I'd like it to take the argument of the preceding query (SomeQueryOnMyTable), but I don't have a clue of how to do this...
Any idea?

**EDIT:** Maybe there is a better way to do this generic filter function, I will eventually accept it as an answer

Comment: Take a look at this [How can I get objects and property values from expression trees?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/03/11/how-can-i-get-objects-and-property-values-from-expression-trees.aspx) Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `predicate(c)` because `c` is of type `MyType`, like this:

```
public static IQueryable<MyType> Filter(this IQueryable<MyType> query, string param, Func<MyType, string> predicate)
{
    var req = query.Where(c =>
        (!(param == null || param.Trim() == "") && predicate(c).StartsWith(param))
            || ((param == null || param.Trim() == "")));

    return req;
}
```